# browsersync.reload() is not working,task is not completed

Tags: npm, gulp

I want an auto reload browser,when I changed the source.
gulpfile.js is below. this code is working if I changed, but always occured error.
because the file is nothing. I suppose 'include' task didn't complete,before reload.

■gulpfile.js

```
const del = require('del');
const fileInclude = require('gulp-file-include');
const browsersync = require('browser-sync').create();
const { gulp,watch,src, dest, series ,parallel} = require('gulp');
const sitemap = require('gulp-sitemap');
function generateXML(cb){
  src('**/*.html',{
    read: false
  })
  .pipe(sitemap({
    siteUrl: 'https://sample.com/'
  }))
  .pipe(dest('dist'));
  cb();
}

function include(cb){    
  src(['./src/**/*','!./src/imgs/**/*'])
  .pipe(fileInclude())
  .pipe(dest('dist'));
  cb();
}

function copyimg(cb){
  src('src/imgs/**/*')
  .pipe(dest('dist/imgs'));
  cb();
}

function cleanDist(cb){
  del.sync('dist');
  cb();
}
function preview(cb){
  browsersync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'dist'
    },
  });
  cb();
}
function watchf(cb){
  watch(['src/**/*',"dist/**/*"],series(generateXML,cleanDist,include,copyimg,reload));
  cb();
}
function reload(cb){
  browsersync.reload();
  cb();
}

exports.default = series(generateXML,cleanDist,include,copyimg,preview,watchf);
exports.build = series(generateXML,cleanDist,include,copyimg);
```

Comment: put a `return` at the beginning of all your tasks like `function include(cb){    
  return src(['./src/**/*','!./src/imgs/**/*']).....}`.

Comment: thank you for you comment. this worked!!